# Why does immutability-helper need `nextObject = object` after checking `nextObject === object`?

Tags: javascript, immutability-helper

The part of [source code](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/blob/fbb6718b2e9d4d877b51a5f0ad7cea9a60bb1fd6/index.js#L73) is:

```js
getAllKeys(spec).forEach(function(key) {
  if (hasOwnProperty.call(commands, key)) {
    var objectWasNextObject = object === nextObject;
    
    nextObject = commands[key](spec[key], nextObject, spec, object);
    if (objectWasNextObject && update.isEquals(nextObject, object)) {
      nextObject = object;
    }
  } else {
    // ...
  }
})
```

and the [`update.isEquals` code](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/blob/fbb6718b2e9d4d877b51a5f0ad7cea9a60bb1fd6/index.js#L45) is

```js
update.isEquals = function(a, b) { return a === b; };
```

Why is `nextObject = object;` needed?
When `isEquals` returns `true`, `nextObject` equals `object` already.

Comment: The code is TypeScript now and in the [most recent commit](//github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/blob/3dc903960b8411da84704052d511c20648c45ead/index.ts#L109), this statement still remains. The [issue](//github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper/issues/105) asking about this apparently explains this.